# Repository pattern on ASP.NET Core with Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How can i implement a Repository pattern with ASP.NET Core Identity?

I found a [solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36287.repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core.aspx) to implement a Repository pattern with ASP.NET Core, but not if you are also using the Identity framework.

The only thing i read is about using a two separate databases: one for Identity tables and another for bussiness data, but i'd like to know if it is possible to implement a repository pattern for a single database on a ASP.NET Core project with Identity.

Comment: It is not about two seperate databases but two seperate contexts. The tables may be in one database, but you shouldn't mix the contexts. It is all about seperation of concerns. You can write your own repository, just don't include the identity tables (as they should not be part of the other context).

Comment: Thank you. Any example on how to use two contexts on the same database with EF Core? And one question: if i should use separate contexts (one for Identity and other for bussiness data), what is the propper way to relate tables in bussiness context with, for example, Identity's user table?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I disagree. Sometimes your users are part of business model and it makes sense to have Identity models and the rest of your models belonging to the same DB context. Especially if you need to have foreign keys to/from users object. I also tried separate contexts and ended up merging them because maintenance overhead was higher than any other benefit of separation.

Comment: @trailmax I can't say I have the same experience. Mixing contexts gave me far more headaches and work than keeping the contexts seperated. And using IdentityServer I can't mix the contexts, as both are on different machines and databases. But it is not just about seperating tables, it's also about putting the information in the right context.

Comment: Thanks to both. I found this link: https://aarcoraci.wordpress.com/2017/03/07/asp-net-core-mvc-entity-framework-repository-pattern/ which seems to follow the Ruard van Elburg recommendations (i haven't read it fully jet), but i couldn't find anything on how to use one database and one context as @trailmax said, and its the way i personally prefer becouse i think that fits better with my application (users have relationships with bussiness tables). So please, give some more info/examples on your approaches, i'm really interested in learning both.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Autofac as your Dependency Injection in asp.net core. here's the documentation on how to use Autofac in your Asp.net Identity Project: [Doc](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)

First Add Identity in your services in Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<User,IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and so on you can register a module in your Service Layer (or Whatever you name it in the repository pattern) and configure them after you register DbContext and your Services:

```
var dbContextParameter = new ResolvedParameter((pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IdentityDbContext),
                                                        (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<DatabaseContext>());

            builder.RegisterType<UserStore<User, IdentityRole<Guid>, DatabaseContext, Guid>>()
                .As<IUserStore<User>>().WithParameter(dbContextParameter).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<UserManager<User>>()
                .As<UserManager<User>>().WithParameter(dbContextParameter).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<SignInManager<User>>()
                .As<SignInManager<User>>().WithParameter(dbContextParameter).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<RoleStore<IdentityRole>>()
                .As<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>().WithParameter(dbContextParameter).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

the code above is the way to register the UserStore, you can make UserManager, SignInManager and other classes like this

note that you can register your Services as their implemented Interfaces like this:

```
var Service = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Service)
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

then you can inject identity services into your Service Constructor like this:

```
 public UserService(Data.IRepositoryX<User> repository, IUnitOfWorkDatabaseContext unit, SignInManager<User> signInManager) : base(repository)
    {

    }
```